# Как правильно сконфигурировать CMakelist файл?

Tags: c++, cmake

У меня есть два набора файлов (основной и дополнительный) и я хотел бы держать их отдетьно друг от друга.

Для первого набора(основного) такая конфигурация была сделана

```
set(libplayersource
        ....
        )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        libplayer

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        ${libplayersource})
```

Для второго (дополнительного) вот такая

```
set(codec_source
        ...)

add_library(libcodec SHARED ${codec_source})
```

В итоге мне нужно все это залинковать

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libplayer
        libcodec)
```

Потом мне еще нужно добавить `log` библиотеку. Для этого мне нужно сначала ее найти и потом добавить

```
find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)
```

Редактирую `target_link_libraries` блок

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libplayer
        libcodec
        ${log-lib})
```

Все хорошо работает если вы собираетесь использовать `log` библиотеку в `libplayer` модуле, но если вы захотите использовать ее в `libcodec` модуле, то получите вот такую ошибку

> undefined reference to `__android_log_print'
>
> clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Линкер не видит имплементации `log` либы для этого модуля. Нашел вот такой ответ на SO

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47803975/5709159

для того, чтоб все заработало мне нужно добавить в `CMakeList` блок

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libcodec
        ${log-lib}
        )
```

---

Теперь имплементация выглядит вот так

```
...
#Main module
set(libplayersource
        ....
        )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        libplayer

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        ${libplayersource})

#Additional module
set(codec_source
        ...)

add_library(libcodec SHARED ${codec_source})

#Log lib
find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

#Linking

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libcodec
        ${log-lib}
        )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libplayer
        libcodec
        ${log-lib})
...
```

То есть мне нужно указать `log` либу в двух модулях.

**Вопрос** - почему линкер не видит в `libcodec`, почему нужно добавлять дополнительный блок:

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libcodec
        ${log-lib}
        )
```

чтоб сделать эту либу видимой для `libcodec` модуля?

**P.S.** В VisualStudio если у тебя есть проект А и две либы В и С то ты их включаешь в проект и все, можно в В использовать С и так далее. Тебе не нужно для того, чтоб методы из С использовать в В добавлять С в В, достаточно того, что эти две либы включены в основной проект А.

Comment: Вы хотите транзитивные зависимости?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы то, что написано работало как задумано:

```
target_link_libraries(libcodec ${log-lib} )
target_link_libraries(libplayer libcodec)
```

Можно сделать две вещи: либо прописать `libcodec` как статическую библиотеку, либо доступ к зависимостям `libcodec` сделать публичным:

```
target_link_libraries(libcodec PUBLIC ${log-lib} )
```

Собственно почему [не работает с `SHARED` и без `PUBLIC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/target_link_libraries.html?highlight=target_link_libraries#libraries-for-both-a-target-and-its-dependents) - эти зависимости попадают в `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`, что не даёт явной линковки либ, а только отмечает, что она может потребоваться.

Небольшое замечание к коду. Не используйте в основном проекте `find_library(log-lib log)`. Сделайте `FindLog.cmake`, если `log-lib` это сторонний не `cmake` проект, а если это ваш проект - сделайте нормальный экспорт конфигурации. Тогда

```
find_package(LogLib)
target_link_libraries(libcodec PUBLIC log::log)
```

избавит от необходимости искать файл либы и добавлять путь до хедеров.

Answer (score 0):

Так посмотрите документацию `target_link_libraries()`.

Первый аргумент -- таргет, к которому линкуете остальные аргументы -- таргеты библиотек. Соответственно, 1 вызов линкует `log_lib` к `libcodec`, а второй -- `libcodec` и `log_lib` к `libplayer`.

Без первого вызова вы к `libcodec` ничего не линкуете, поэтому получаете ошибку.